# debhelper and fun question about dh_make

Tags: debian, iso, debian-installer

I create an distro about 6 years ago, i recall i used `dh_make command`, i have a suggesstion for creating distro recently, When i use :

```
root@debian:/home/mohsen# dpkg -L debhelper |egrep dh_make
/usr/bin/dh_makeshlibs
/usr/share/man/man1/dh_makeshlibs.1.gz
/usr/share/man/es/man1/dh_makeshlibs.1.gz
/usr/share/man/fr/man1/dh_makeshlibs.1.gz
/usr/share/man/de/man1/dh_makeshlibs.1.gz
```

I'm confused.Why `dh_make` doesn't exist? I decide to use `debian installer` ,`debhelper` and `deboostrap`,  But i don't know dh_make has been eliminated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dh_make` is contained in the `dh-make` package. You need to install that.